# If issue in for loop

Tags: json, string, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop where I want to find an email.I have to strings which are for sure identical. In the for loop i put a toast and i saw that both show the same thing without any white spaces. What I have in if(String == String ) doesn't happen at all.
Here is the code :

```
try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_email = null;

        for(int i=0;i<=jArray.length();i++){
            json_email = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            addedby2 = json_email.getString("email");



        if(addedby2==email2){
            Toast.makeText(this, json_email.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            user = json_email.getString("user");
            rpoints = json_email.getString("respectpoints");
            //Toast.makeText(this, user+"    "+rpoints, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        tvAdded.setText(user + " (" + rpoints + ")");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also tried to getString("user") outside the if condition and it worked.
I tried in if condition to write : String.equals(String) but without any result.

Does anyone know what the issue could be ?

Comment: Compare your strings using `equals` (see *[How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)*). If the issue is still there look at the values of both variables.

Comment: try single stepping through it, e.g. in Firebug.

Comment: Try if string.compareTo(other_string)==0

Comment: I solved it. The mistake is that I used "<=Array.length()" instead of "<". Thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java, to compare string values, you have to use the equals() function. Like Howard said, if that doesn't work, then your variables might be wrong.

Comment: I solved it. The mistake is that I used "<=Array.length()" instead of "<". Thank you all anyway. PS: It works in java to compare two strings using == .